# How to express the relationship that two numbers are not equal?

Tags: word-usage

I know that for two numbers `x` and `y`, relationships like  `x < y` (and `x <= y` sometimes) are called inequalities. Note here, there is an order between x and y, for example (`3 < 5`).

But what's the correct usage to express the relationship that two numbers are merely not equal to each other, i.e. `x <> y`?

Do we also call this an "inequality" (could be confusing) or do we call this something else?

I tried to use unequality, and spell checkers always tell me it's wrong.

Comment: "These two numbers are equal".... "These two numbers are **unequal**"...

Comment: This might be a better fit for the math section of SE.

Comment: Unequal, not equal, not the same, different....  (And spell checker is only there as an assist.  Use a dictionary to check the spelling of words you're unsure of.)

Comment: (How is "inequality" confusing?)

Comment: Have you looked up 'inequality' and 'unequal'?

Comment: Can you edit your post to specify a sentence that you want to use this word? Are you looking for an adjective or a noun or what?

Comment: Eg, There are only two cases for two numbers x and y, equality and unequality.

Comment: `<>` is the _inequality operator_ for Pascal (and Pascal-like) languages; the expression `A <> B` is true when A and B are not equal. It differs from the other inequality operators in that there is no specified order of operation.

Comment: @HotLicks I think it's confusing because when we say we "solve a system of inequalities", it's usually things like `x <=5`, `x > 3` and so on. If you put `x <> 3` into a system of "inequalities", it kind of breaks down.

Comment: Refer to this question ([link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301271/inequality-vs-inequation-equation-vs-equality)).

Comment: @tinlynx The answer to your question is: ≠ which means “not equal to”. If A is merely not (exactly) equal to B, we write A ≠ B. This is a kind of inequality. There are many, like < > ≤ ≥ ≈ ≉ ≮ ≯. There is an inequality symbol for every specific case of not being equal or approximately/almost equal.

Comment: The word ‘inequality’ is interchangeable with ‘inequation’ in mathematics and usage is a matter of preference. Same for ‘equality’ and ‘equation’. (Refer to Wolfram Mathworld.) Mathematicians mostly discuss ‘inequalities’ (not inequations) but solve equations (not equalities). My middle school Australian mathematics textbook has “solving linear inequations” because it comes right after “solving linear equations”, and switching term would be unnecessarily confusing for younger learners. [I can’t post an answer because the thread is closed. Hope this helps.]

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is ***inequality***.

The [Merriam Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inequality) defines *inequality* as:

> **1** the quality of being unequal or uneven... Middle English *inequalite*, from Latin *inaequalitat-*, *inaequalitas*, from *inaequalis*
>   unequal, from *in-* + *aequalis* equal First Known Use: 15th century

Comment: Doesn't quite fit the OP; "express the relationship that two numbers are merely not equal to each other"... 'The values 7 and 23 are ______", though I suppose you *could* say "7 and 23 *have* inequality", but it seems a bit clunky...

Comment: @MarvMills - Where does the OP say "The values 7 and 23 are ______"?

Comment: @HotLicks Clearly the OP does not- it is practical example of a sentence using the form the OP *does* imply, showing that the suggestion in this answer would not work as well. I am sure you knew that.

Comment: @MarvMills - So, why don't you answer the question?

Comment: @HotLicks why don't you? This line of questioning is off-topic and pointless. I'm out.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, it is common to say that two numbers are *distinct*.

> x and y are **distinct** integers.
>
> x, y, and z are (pairwise) **distinct** integers.

Comment: What about 'unequal'?

Answer (score 0):

Some mathematicians and computer scientists have tried to introduce "disequality" to mean a statement that two numbers (or other entities) are distinct.  As far as I can tell, this suggestion is not catching on.