# What do you call a '>' relation between two unknowns?

Tags: word-usage, mathematics

I know that in mathematics, the relation `a = 2b` is called an **equation**.

Is the relation `a > 2b` still called an **equation** or is it called something else?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [Inequality vs. Inequation, Equation vs. Equality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301271/inequality-vs-inequation-equation-vs-equality).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The example you give, `a > 2b`, is called an **inequality**.
In my grade-school math classes we used the term "inequality" to refer even to expressions like `a ≥ 2b`; language can be messy sometimes.

Equations, inequalities, and expressions like `a ∈ ℚ` and "b is prime" are all **constraints**.

Answer (score 4):

Your question seems to me to provide its own answer. The word **relation** is often used in this context, it avoids needless debate about whether a ≥ 2b is an inequality or not, and if anyone wants to know exactly what kind of relation they need only look at the mathematical notation.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't "relation" refer to the *result* of the constraint `a ≥ 2b`, and not the constraint itself?

Comment: @JohnWu  I am not quite sure what you mean by the result in this context. Certainly in the kind of papers and books I read relation has the meaning I have suggested in my answer.

Comment: @JeremyC To me "relation" or "relationship" is not specific, it covers all of "greater than", "less than", "greater than or equal to", "less than or equal to", "equal to", "not equal to", "approximately equal to", "equivalent to", "congruant to", "similar to" and probably others that I've forgotton. However only the first four are usually referred to as "inequalities": even "not equal to", which is specifically unequal, is not usually referred to as an "inequality".